# Local database server available on local network?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, xampp

I just installed XAMPP and I'm using the control panel v3.2.1 and I have successfully created my own local MySQL database, but what I want to do, and after more than 20 google searches, I couldn't find my answer, however, I want to make my database available to the local network, so that anyone connected to my router will be able to connect and retrieve data from my MySQL server, is this possible?
And if so, can anyone link to some documentation on the matter or maybe tell me how to do so?

I have changed the bind-adress to "0.0.0.0" and I've run this query in phpmyadmin

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST="0.0.0.0", MASTER_PORT=3306,
MASTER_USER="root", MASTER_PASSWORD="" ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to set up a MASTER-SLAVE cause that is what the 'query' you executed there is doing...

Comment: I was trying to set up a master server which all the other computers can use on my network, did I state that poorly in my question? :/

Comment: yeah but you are not trying to set up a Master-Slave. where did you read that you should execute that?  I think you have the wrong idea of what a "Master Server" is.. what OS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track, but went down the wrong path somewhere along the way.

Comment out the bind-address in your `my.cnf/my.ini` (depending on OS). Then restart mysql so that the changes to the `my.cnf/my.ini` file will take affect. You can read more here at [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-allow-remote-mysql-database-connection). Now, anyone will be able to connect to your Mysql database remotely as long as they have proper user credentials.

So, now you want people on your local network to be able to connect.  Say, your local internal network is `192.168.1.1`.  You can make a users for the other people on your network by executing create user `'username'@'192.168.1.%' Identified by password 'userpassword'`.

The wild card (`%`) in the above `192.168.1.%` will allow that user to connect from any of the IP's on the `192.168.1.1` network, regardless of what IP the user is allocted via DHCP.  Note: If you just used the `%` then the user would be able to connect from any IP.

You can read more about adding users [@dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-users.html).

Also in order for the user to be able to select, update, delete, etc.. data you also have to grant privileges to the user. You need to execute something like this: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'192.168.1.%';`

You can read more about granting privileges [@dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Comment: Now I have done exactly as you said, will this allow a MySQL connection to any of my databases on this computer?

Comment: Because I couldn't connect to "http://localhost" from my other computer after that I just did what you said

Comment: Oooh, but how do I then connect to phpmyadmin from the other computer isn't that going trough localhost/phpmyadmin?

Comment: Why would I else add a user if not go to phpmyadmin?

Comment: Or, you are saying that I can do that with a connection query in php or java for example but not trough phpmyadmin?